# Hide sensitive data in debugger snapshots

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-debugging, azure-application-insights

We've enabled snapshot debugging which we found really helpful. However there are situations where we have sensitive data in local variables that ideally should not be available to inspect in the snapshots. Does anybody know if it is possible to hide/obscure specific properties/classes in the snapshots?

Comment: The mere fact that the garbage collector does not and cannot track what data you consider "sensitive" would seem to make this a hopeless exercise, because even with variables obscured, copies of sensitive data could be floating around in memory. You'd have to have some sort of symbolic debugger to even make this work (which, in turn, would make other issues much harder to troubleshoot) and I'm pretty sure the current technology just uses memory snapshots -- just like your regular desktop debugger, for that matter.

Comment: I wish we could use debugger snapshots but, because of the same reasons that the OP has indicated, we can't use it.